# SQL Dynamically generate columns based on a map table

Tags: sql, dynamic, google-bigquery, pivot

I would like to dynamically generate a table based on other mapping table. I have a map table that looks like, this map table is connected to an excel and can be modified by the users adding as many rows as they wish:

| Name | ColumnName |
| --- | --- |
| banner | banner_flag |
| pop_up | pop_up_flag |

Then I have a source table that looks like:

| id | language | transactions | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | es-es | 0 | banner |
| 02 | es-mx | 0 | loggin |
| 03 | es-es | 1 | pop_up |
| 03 | es-es | 1 | banner |
| 03 | es-es | 1 | loggin |
| 03 | es-es | 1 | back_home |
| 04 | es-es | 0 | loggin |
| 04 | es-es | 0 | banner |
| 04 | es-es | 0 | banner |
| 05 | es-es | 1 | loggin |
| 06 | es-es | 2 | loggin |

Then the final output would look like:

| id | language | transactions | banner_flag | pop_up_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | es-es | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 02 | es-mx | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | es-es | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 04 | es-es | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 05 | es-es | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 06 | es-es | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Where the columns associated to the map table are calculated fields that in pseucode would look like:

```
for x in map_table.ColumnName:
  if x in sourceTable.Column:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: how is the transaction column being calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''select * from (
  select id, language, sum(if(action = Name, 0, transactions)) as transactions, ColumnName, countif(action = Name) as flag
  from source_table s
  cross join map m 
  group by id, language, ColumnName
)
pivot (sum(flag) for ColumnName in ("''' || list || '''"))
order by id
''' 
from (select string_agg(distinct ColumnName, '","') as list from map)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]